# Default unit for time based steps in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Having this line in Jenkinsfile written by someone else:

```
timeout(3) {
 . . .
```

I couldn't figure out which unit this argument "3" represents: seconds, minutes... Then I checked [Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-timeout-code-enforce-time-limit) but there is no word about default time unit. Sleep step has the same problem.

So what is the default time unit for Jenkins pipelines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at plugin's [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/TimeoutStep.java) it is clear that MINUTES is default time unit for timeout step. For sleep step it is SECONDS.